# Can't able to sync between label of checkbox and box of chekbox in new plugin

Tags: extjs

I have created new plugin which extend another extended type.
Problem is,

1. When i click on "All" option in combo then disable value is also getting selected.
2. When i click on label of checkbox in combo list then tick on box is not appearing and when i click on that box then it work fine.

Here is Code which i have extended

```
    Ext.define('Ext.ux.CheckCombo',
{

    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.checkcombo',
    multiSelect: true,
    allSelector: false,
    noData: false,
    noDataText: '',
    addAllSelector: false,
    allSelectorHidden: false,
    enableKeyEvents: true,
    afterExpandCheck: false,
    allText: 'All',
    oldValue: '',
    //matchFieldWidth: true,
    //listConfig: {minWidth: 50},
    listeners:
    {
/* uncomment if you want to reload store on every combo expand
        beforequery: function(qe)
        {
            this.store.removeAll();
            delete qe.combo.lastQuery;
        },
*/
        focus: function(cpt)
        {

            cpt.oldValue = cpt.getValue();
        },
        keydown: function(cpt, e, eOpts)
        {
            var    value = cpt.getRawValue(),
                oldValue = cpt.oldValue;

            // below line is commented bcz  we are getting  value as data  and  oldvalue  as ids
           // if(value != oldValue) cpt.setValue('');
        }
    },
    createPicker: function()
    {
        var    me = this,
            picker,
            menuCls = Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'menu',
            opts = Ext.apply(
            {
                pickerField: me,
                selModel:
                {
                    mode: me.multiSelect ? 'SIMPLE' : 'SINGLE'
                },
                floating: true,
                hidden: true,
                ownerCt: me.ownerCt,
                cls: me.el.up('.' + menuCls) ? menuCls : '',
                store: me.store,
                displayField: me.displayField,
                focusOnToFront: false,
                pageSize: me.pageSize,
                tpl:
                [
                    '<ul><tpl for=".">',
                        '<li role="option"   class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'boundlist-item"><span class="x-combo-checker">&nbsp;</span> {' + me.displayField + '}</li>',
                    '</tpl></ul>'
                ]
            }, me.listConfig, me.defaultListConfig);


        picker = me.picker = Ext.create('Ext.view.BoundList', opts);
        if(me.pageSize)
        {
            picker.pagingToolbar.on('beforechange', me.onPageChange, me);
        }        


        me.mon(picker,
        {
            itemclick: me.onItemClick,
            refresh: me.onListRefresh,
            scope: me
        });


        me.mon(picker.getSelectionModel(),
        {
            'beforeselect': me.onBeforeSelect,
            'beforedeselect': me.onBeforeDeselect,
            'selectionchange': me.onListSelectionChange,
            scope: me
        });


        me.store.on('load', function(store)
        {
            if(store.getTotalCount() == 0)
            {
                me.allSelectorHidden = true;
                if(me.allSelector != false) me.allSelector.setStyle('display', 'none');
                if(me.noData != false) me.noData.setStyle('display', 'block');
            }
            else
            {
                me.allSelectorHidden = false;
                if(me.allSelector != false) me.allSelector.setStyle('display', 'block');
                if(me.noData != false) me.noData.setStyle('display', 'none');
            }
        });


        return picker;
    },
    reset: function()
    {
        var    me = this;


        me.setValue('');
    },
    setValue: function(value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        if(!value)
        {
            if(this.allSelector != false) this.allSelector.removeCls('x-boundlist-selected');
            return this.callParent(arguments);
        }


        if(typeof value == 'string')
        {
            var    me = this,
                records = [],
                vals = value.split(',');

            if(value == '')
            {
                if(me.allSelector != false) me.allSelector.removeCls('x-boundlist-selected');
            }
            else
            {
                if(vals.length == me.store.getCount() && vals.length != 0)
                {
                    if(me.allSelector != false) me.allSelector.addCls('x-boundlist-selected');
                    else me.afterExpandCheck = true;
                }
            }


            Ext.each(vals, function(val)
            {
                var record = me.store.getById(parseInt(val));
                if(record) records.push(record);
            });


            return me.setValue(records);
        }
        else return this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    getValue: function()
    {
        if(typeof this.value == 'object') return this.value.join(',');
        else return this.value;
    },
    getSubmitValue: function()
    {
        return this.getValue();
    },
    expand: function()
    {
        var    me = this,
            bodyEl, picker, collapseIf;


            if(me.rendered && !me.isExpanded && !me.isDestroyed)
            {
            bodyEl = me.bodyEl;
            picker = me.getPicker();
            collapseIf = me.collapseIf;


            // show the picker and set isExpanded flag
            picker.show();
            me.isExpanded = true;
            me.alignPicker();
            bodyEl.addCls(me.openCls);

            if(me.noData == false) me.noData = picker.getEl().down('.x-boundlist-list-ct').insertHtml('beforeBegin', '<div class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">'+me.noDataText+'</div>', true);
            if(me.addAllSelector == true && me.allSelector == false)
            {
                var selectedvalues =  this.value ;
                  var vals =  String(selectedvalues).split(",");
                if(vals.length == me.store.getCount() && vals.length != 0)
                {
                me.allSelector = picker.getEl().down('.x-boundlist-list-ct').insertHtml('beforeBegin', '<div class="x-boundlist-item x-boundlist-selected" role="option"><span class="x-combo-checker">&nbsp;</span> '+me.allText+'</div>', true);
                }
                else
                {
                 me.allSelector = picker.getEl().down('.x-boundlist-list-ct').insertHtml('beforeBegin', '<div class="x-boundlist-item" role="option"><span class="x-combo-checker">&nbsp;</span> '+me.allText+'</div>', true);
                }
                me.allSelector.on('click', function(e)
                {
                    if(me.allSelector.hasCls('x-boundlist-selected'))
                    {
                        me.allSelector.removeCls('x-boundlist-selected');
                        me.setValue('');
                        me.fireEvent('select', me, []);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var records = [];
                        me.store.each(function(record)
                        {
                            records.push(record);
                        });
                        me.allSelector.addCls('x-boundlist-selected');
                        me.select(records);
                        me.fireEvent('select', me, records);
                    }
                });


                if(me.allSelectorHidden == true) me.allSelector.hide();
                else me.allSelector.show();

                if(me.afterExpandCheck == true)
                {
                    me.allSelector.addCls('x-boundlist-selected');
                    me.afterExpandCheck = false;
                }
            }


            // monitor clicking and mousewheel
            me.mon(Ext.getDoc(),
            {
                mousewheel: collapseIf,
                mousedown: collapseIf,
                scope: me
            });
            Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(me.alignPicker, me);
            me.fireEvent('expand', me);
            me.onExpand();
        }
        else
        {
            me.fireEvent('expand', me);
            me.onExpand();
        }
    },
    alignPicker: function()
    {    
        var me = this,
            picker = me.getPicker();


        me.callParent();

        if(me.addAllSelector == true)
        {
            var height = picker.getHeight();
            //alert(height);
            height = parseInt(height)+25;
            picker.setHeight(height);
           picker.getEl().setStyle('height', height+'px');
        }
    },
    onListSelectionChange: function(list, selectedRecords)
    {
        var    me = this,
            isMulti = me.multiSelect,
            hasRecords = selectedRecords.length > 0;
        // Only react to selection if it is not called from setValue, and if our list is
        // expanded (ignores changes to the selection model triggered elsewhere)
        if(!me.ignoreSelection && me.isExpanded)
        {
            if(!isMulti)
            {
                Ext.defer(me.collapse, 1, me);
            }
            /*
            * Only set the value here if we're in multi selection mode or we have
            * a selection. Otherwise setValue will be called with an empty value
            * which will cause the change event to fire twice.
            */
            if(isMulti || hasRecords)
            {
                me.setValue(selectedRecords, false);
            }
            if(hasRecords)
            {
                me.fireEvent('select', me, selectedRecords);
            }
            me.inputEl.focus();

            if(me.addAllSelector == true && me.allSelector != false)
            {
                if(selectedRecords.length == me.store.getTotalCount()) me.allSelector.addCls('x-boundlist-selected');
                else me.allSelector.removeCls('x-boundlist-selected');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And here is extended code,

```
    Ext.define('Ext.ux.PermissionCheckCombo',{
    extend: 'Ext.ux.CheckCombo',                
    alias: 'widget.permissioncheckcombo',  
    frame: false,
    createPicker: function()
    {
        var me = this,
        picker,
        menuCls = Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'menu',
        opts = Ext.apply(
        {
            pickerField: me,
            selModel:
            {
                mode: me.multiSelect ? 'SIMPLE' : 'SINGLE'
            },
            floating: true,
            hidden: true,            
            ownerCt: me.ownerCt,
            cls: me.el.up('.' + menuCls) ? menuCls : '',
            store: me.store,
            displayField: me.displayField,
            focusOnToFront: false,
            pageSize: me.pageSize,
            disableField: me.disableField,
            bind: {
                store: this.store
            },
             listeners: {                           
                    beforeselect: function(combo, record, index ) {
                        if (record.get(me.disableField) != 0) {
                            // combo.setValue(record.get(me.displayField));
                            // combo.setValue(record.get(me.displayField));
                            // console.log(combo);
                        } else {                            
                            return false;
                        }
                        // Cancel the default action
                    }

                },

            tpl:
            [
                '<ul><tpl for=".">',
                //    '<li role="option"   class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'boundlist-item"><span class="x-combo-checker">&nbsp;</span> {' + me.displayField + '}</li>',
                '<tpl if=" ' + me.disableField + ' &gt; 0 ">',
                  '<li role="option"   class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'boundlist-item"><span><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;</span> {' + me.displayField + '}</li>',
                '<tpl else>',
                 '<li role="option"   class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'boundlist-item" ><span><input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled"/>&nbsp;</span> {' + me.displayField + '}</li>',
                '</tpl>',
              /*  '<div class="x-boundlist-item">',
                    '<tpl if=" ' + this.disableField + ' == false ">',
                       '<div class="nowrap">',
                           '<input type="checkbox"/>',
                               '{',
                                   this.displayField,
                               '}',
                       '</div>',
                   '</tpl>',
                   '<tpl if=" ' + this.disableField + ' == true ">',
                       '<div class="nowrap">',
                           '<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" />',
                               '{',
                                   this.displayField,
                               '}',
                       '</div>',
                   '</tpl>',
                '</div>', */
            '</tpl></ul>'

            ]
        }, me.listConfig, me.defaultListConfig);


        picker = me.picker = Ext.create('Ext.view.BoundList', opts);
        if(me.pageSize)
        {
            picker.pagingToolbar.on('beforechange', me.onPageChange, me);
        }        


        me.mon(picker,
        {
            itemclick: me.onItemClick,
            refresh: me.onListRefresh,
            scope: me
        });


        me.mon(picker.getSelectionModel(),
        {
            'beforeselect': me.onBeforeSelect,
            'beforedeselect': me.onBeforeDeselect,
            'selectionchange': me.onListSelectionChange,
            scope: me
        });


        me.store.on('load', function(store)
        {
            if(store.getTotalCount() == 0)
            {
                me.allSelectorHidden = true;
                if(me.allSelector != false) me.allSelector.setStyle('display', 'none');
                if(me.noData != false) me.noData.setStyle('display', 'block');
            }
            else
            {
                me.allSelectorHidden = false;
                if(me.allSelector != false) me.allSelector.setStyle('display', 'block');
                if(me.noData != false) me.noData.setStyle('display', 'none');
            }
        });

        return picker;
    },

    expand: function()
    {
        var    me = this,
            bodyEl, picker, collapseIf;


            if(me.rendered && !me.isExpanded && !me.isDestroyed)
            {
            bodyEl = me.bodyEl;
            picker = me.getPicker();
            collapseIf = me.collapseIf;


            // show the picker and set isExpanded flag
            picker.show();
            me.isExpanded = true;
            me.alignPicker();
            bodyEl.addCls(me.openCls);

            if(me.noData == false) me.noData = picker.getEl().down('.x-boundlist-list-ct').insertHtml('beforeBegin', '<div class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">'+me.noDataText+'</div>', true);
            if(me.addAllSelector == true && me.allSelector == false)
            {
                var selectedvalues =  this.value ;
                  var vals =  String(selectedvalues).split(",");
                if(vals.length == me.store.getCount() && vals.length != 0)
                {
                me.allSelector = picker.getEl().down('.x-boundlist-list-ct').insertHtml('beforeBegin', '<div class="x-boundlist-item x-boundlist-selected" role="option"><span ><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;</span> '+me.allText+'</div>', true);
                }
                else
                {
                 me.allSelector = picker.getEl().down('.x-boundlist-list-ct').insertHtml('beforeBegin', '<div class="x-boundlist-item" role="option"><span ><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;</span> '+me.allText+'</div>', true);
                }
                me.allSelector.on('click', function(e)
                {
                    if(me.allSelector.hasCls('x-boundlist-selected'))
                    {
                        me.allSelector.removeCls('x-boundlist-selected');
                        me.setValue('');
                        me.fireEvent('select', me, []);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var records = [];
                        me.store.each(function(record)
                        {
                            records.push(record);
                        });
                        me.allSelector.addCls('x-boundlist-selected');
                        me.select(records);
                        me.fireEvent('select', me, records);
                    }
                });


                if(me.allSelectorHidden == true) me.allSelector.hide();
                else me.allSelector.show();

                if(me.afterExpandCheck == true)
                {
                    me.allSelector.addCls('x-boundlist-selected');
                    me.afterExpandCheck = false;
                }
            }


            // monitor clicking and mousewheel
            me.mon(Ext.getDoc(),
            {
                mousewheel: collapseIf,
                mousedown: collapseIf,
                scope: me
            });
            Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(me.alignPicker, me);
            me.fireEvent('expand', me);
            me.onExpand();
        }
        else
        {
            me.fireEvent('expand', me);
            me.onExpand();
        }
    },
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Issue for disable checkbox in list is resolved. But there is one more issue, in checkcombo there is "ALL" option, when i click on that all values are getting selected(disabled too). So how should i solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. It might be helpful for someone. :)

Here is solution: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?295648-Ext.ux.PerCheckCombo